# Alfresco : How to get value from Postgresql DB show to workflow from dropdown list?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have created advanced workflow(Example:- Client name, client code,employees) ,User use the workflow store data's into alfresco database,Now I want get all stored from alfresco once get the data i need use the another workflow drop-down control

Comment: Hi, this is quite hard to understand you. Could you please explain what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

In workflow form configuration file,there must be an ftl file reference which will be responsible for drop down.You need to customize that freemarker template file.

In customized free marker template you need to call one webscript which will return data from database.

For the reference you can refer below link.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-custom-formcontrol.html